# Unable to install 32-bit Gtk on RedHat 7: Protected multilib versions

Tags: centos, rhel, yum, 64bit, 32bit

I'm trying to install a 32-bit version of the GTK onto a RedHat 7 Enterprise system. As the system isn't yet registered with Red Hat, I've gone ahead and used a Centos 7 repo for now. If I understand correctly, the two systems don't differ, so this shouldn't be an issue.

The reason I'm installing (or trying to install) a 32-bit version is to support a legacy application.

Here's the command I'm running into the problem with:

```
yum install gtk2-2.24.31-1.el7.i686
```

When I type it in, it comes back with this result:

```
Protected multilib versions: mesa-libgbm-18.0.5-3.el7.i686 != mesa-libgbm-18.0.5-4.el7_6.x86_64

Error: Protected multilib versions: mesa-libEGL-18.0.5-3.el7.i686 != mesa-libEGL-18.0.5-4.el7_6.x86_64

Error: Protected multilib versions: systemd-libs-219-62.el7.i686 != systemd-libs-219-62.el7_6.5.x86_64

Error: Protected multilib versions: mesa-libglapi-18.0.5-3.el7.i686 != mesa-libglapi-18.0.5-4.el7_6.x86_64

Error: Protected multilib versions: mesa-libGL-18.0.5-3.el7.i686 != mesa-libGL-18.0.5-4.el7_6.x86_64

Error: Protected multilib versions: krb5-libs-1.15.1-34.el7.i686 != krb5-libs-1.15.1-37.el7_6.x86_64
```

According to this link:

https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=mmr_kc-0131971,

I've done the following:

```
yum search gtk2 --showduplicates | grep -v x86_64
```

The result includes the 64-bit version (I'm trying to install the 32-bit version).

```
gtk2-2.24.31-1.el7.i686
```

I then do the following, to see the installed 64-bit version:

```
rpm -q gtk2
```

Which shows this:

```
gtk2-2.24.31-1.el7.x86_64
```

Then, following along with the instructions, I do the above listed install:

```
  yum install gtk2-2.24.31-1.el7.i686
```

with the resulting error messages as shown above.

I've looked at uninstalling the 64-bit mesa-libraries, but there are 3.2 Gigs worth of apps that depend on it.

I thought I was onto something with that post, because the point was to assure that the 32-bit libraries would be compatible with the 64-bit libraries. However, unlike in the post, the underlying libraries don't have the same versions:

```
Protected multilib versions: mesa-libgbm-18.0.5-3.el7.i686 != mesa-libgbm-18.0.5-4.el7_6.x86_64
```

As you can see, the mesa-libgbm-18.0.5-3.el7.i686 version number (18.0.5-3.el7) is a little bit different than the 32-bit counterpart (18.0.5-4.el7_6).

Comment: Firstly, RHEL and CentOS are not the same. They are different distributions and have different repositories. Sometimes, it's possible to install CentOS packages in RHEL but it's not a good idea because there can eventually be a package conflict which is what you are seeing now. You've probably already installed packages from that repo which are incompatible with what's on the system and if you do eventually register it, it's going to be even worse. This is why you are getting package conflicts.

Comment: It's not a good idea to add Ubuntu repos to install Ubuntu packages into Debian or Mint and this is no different. If the system isn't registered then just install CentOS so that you don't have these issues.

Comment: I see your point. The problem is that the computer is from a different company, they are going with RedHat, and they just want to see if our legacy (32-bit) software will run on it. Unfortunately, when I try to access the RedHat repository, it returns a 502 bad gateway error. I don't know if the system is officially registered with RedHat yet. I would like to have access to RedHat's forums, because it looks like a bunch of people have run into this problem. Ideally, create a ticket with RH if that doesn't work. But I don't know the level of subscription they have . It's kind of awkward.

Comment: If the system isn't registered then you don't get support which means that you can't put in tickets or access the forums in addition to the repos not being available. To see if it's registered, you can use the command `subscription-manager status`. As this is the computer of another company then it's up to them to buy a subscription and register the machine. In the meantime, it's not a good idea to add repos from another distro and install packages from them and render the machine unusable.

Comment: Yes, I agree, I will check their subscription status. They did have the RH Enterprise repo installed, so I don't know how they set it up without the active subscription. Also, there's no sense giving them back a system with repos from another machine, although the basic idea is just to see if we can get our software working on it, we can always dot the i's later on. It would be nice if I could just get gimp installed, as I was able to with libXtst.686 and glibc.686. For some reason, thought the GTK is causing more of a ruckus. I think it might be those minor differences in the libraries.

Comment: If you want to see if your company's software will work on their machine then it's better that they provide a machine that's registered and functioning and able to download and install packages from Red Hat's repos. I recommend doing that before you proceed any further even if you have to go to their company and test the software there.